# How to get last login details/time for all users?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I am trying to remove the user accounts which are inactive from last 30 days. 
I tried fetching User Information List. Checked all of it's properties and fields but coudn't find anything related to last login time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public DateTime Get(string attr, string UserName)
        {

            DomainConfiguration domainConfig = new DomainConfiguration();
            using (new SPMonitoredScope("AD Properties"))
            {
                using (DirectoryEntry domain = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainConfig.DomainName, domainConfig.UserName, domainConfig.Password))
                {
                    //DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domain, "(|(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=container)(objectClass=builtinDomain)(objectClass=domainDNS))");
                    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domain);
                    searcher.PageSize = 1000;
                    searcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName='" + UserName + "')";
                    //searcher.Filter = "(|(objectCategory=group)(objectCategory=person))";
                    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (cn=" + UserName + "))";
                    var user = searcher.FindOne();
                    DateTime LastLogon = DateTime.FromFileTime((Int64)user.Properties["lastLogon"].Value);
                    return LastLogon;
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this Helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it does gives me the some older dates than i expected.
but at least it will compile and run.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

private static DateTime? GetUserIdFromDisplayName(string displayName)
    {
        // set up domain context
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            // find user by display name
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, displayName);


            if (user != null)
            {
                return user.LastLogon; 
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        } 
    }
```